# Why I have to call alert once to make the javascript working?

Tags: jquery

This issue is really weird. What I want to do is to add checked box value to a hidden field, and remove the value from the hidden field if it is unchecked. I use javascript to implement this, however, I found that only I call alert once, the code works, otherwise, it won't. Can anyone tell me why?

```
var cpo={
    AddCheckList:function(){
    alert('aaaaaaaaaa'); //If I comment this line, the following code won't work.
    $(".BillChecked").change(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                var idList = $('#CPO_BillList').val() + $(this).attr('value') + ",";
                $('#CPO_BillList').val(idList);
            } else {
                var temp = $('#CPO_BillList').val().replace($(this).attr('value') + ',', '');
                $('#CPO_BillList').val(temp);
            }
            alert($('#CPO_BillList').val());
    });
}
```

I call
           cpo.AddCheckList();
at the bottom of the page.

Above is the $(document).ready() function. only works when there is an alert method being called once.

Comment: Why are you looping to bind the change event?  that's unnecessary..  Also do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Probably because you did not put this code *in* the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

Comment: But how come the code works, if I didn't comment the first line?

Comment: @Steven because the alert delays the execution of the rest of the javascript.

Comment: @Christoph: make sense. So do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @wirey: you are right, I'm going to remove the looping

Comment: well, you missed some important information about your code - either put it IN `$(document).ready(function{/*code here*/});` or place the script block at the bottom of your document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, check the code and also avoid doing loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var billChecked = $(".BillChecked");
    var cpoBill = $('#CPO_BillList');

    var cpo = {AddCheckList:function(){

        billChecked.change(function(){

            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            var billVal = $(this).val();

            checked ? v = cpoBill.val() + billVal : v = cpoBill.val().replace(billVal + ',', '');
            cpoBill.val(v);
        });
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The alert dialog blocks the execution of the rest of your javascript. One of the following will work:

put the code in

```
$(document).ready(function{
    /*code here*/
});
```

or place the script-block at the bottom of your `<body>` tag.

Also you should store `$(".BillChecked")` in a variable because every jQuery-call with a Selector inside is pretty costly.

```
var $billChecked = $(".BillChecked");
```

Comment: I just updated my post, I actually put the code at the bottom of the page, but still if I comment the alert, it does not work

Comment: @steven so put this into doument.ready and it will definitely work.

Comment: and the the alert window pop up when load the page, if I don't comment the alert('aaaaaaaaaa');